# Laravel blade template extending two different layouts

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I have two templates that are almost identical. It's the mail template, but it should be in two different places. So they are extending the two different templates, but this and the section names are the only differences.

Here's the example:

```
@extends('layout.client')
    //sections etc
@section('content')
    //content here
@endsection
    //other sections etc
```

And here's the second template:

```
@extends('layout.company')
    //sections etc
@section('contentinner')
    //content here
@endsection
    //other sections etc
```

The other sections are mostly imported libraries to make the content work.

How should I approach this to not repeat the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another template and include in your section

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  @include('layouts.your_template')
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue using [components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots).

I found that it is good to have one master layout, but if you have parts of the code you need to include in many pages, it is better to use components. [This](https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/09354df671e2c48eafe7a5cb91bb0f41) provides an excellent example of the use of components.

Put your template into `components.yourtemplate.blade.php`

then in both `layout.client` and `layout.company` put

```
@component('components.yourtemplate')
@endcomponent
```

where you want your template code to be included. You can include the same component in many views.